# Why does my custom IPN processing script stop executing?

Tags: php, pdo, paypal-ipn

I'm building a custom IPN handler in PHP, which validates the data Paypal sends in a postback, and then inserts some of it into an sqlite database.

Every part of the script has worked before.
Transactions get reported as valid, and logged. Everything works, up to line 32, which calls a custom function.

Here's line 32:
`$sql = insert_query_builder("PP_Data", $keywords);`

and here's how the function's defined, in a `require()`'d file:

```
function insert_query_builder($table, $keywords, $info = NULL) {
        $sql_1 = "INSERT INTO $table (";
        $sql_2 = ") VALUES (";
        foreach ( $keywords as $num => $keyword ) {
            if (isset($info)) {
                if ($num != (count($keywords - 1))) {
                    $sql_2 .= $db->quote($info[$keyword]) . ", ";
                    $sql_1 .= $keyword . ", ";
                } else {
                    $sql_2 .= $db->quote($info[$keyword]) . ")";
                    $sql_1 .= $keyword;
                }
            } else {
                if ($num != (count($keywords - 1))) {
                    $sql_2 .= $db->quote($_POST[$keyword]) . ", ";
                    $sql_1 .= $keyword . ", ";
                } else {
                    $sql_2 .= $db->quote($_POST[$keyword]) . ")";
                    $sql_1 .= $keyword;
                }
            }
        }
        $sql = $sql_1 . $_sql_2;
        return $sql;
}
```

This code has worked. the SQL statement it generates is then used on the DB, and it's responsible for one of the rows in the DB.

Even so, now it fails silently. The script works, otherwise.

[here](http://pastebin.com/u/fitzmorrispr) you can find complete copies of all three files used, and the log file.
As you can see, it's not writing anything to the log after the custom function

and, when i put that last working `file_put_contents()` just after it, it stops working.

Any ideas? doing a `php -f IPNrx.php` gives no output, and logs an invalid transaction, like it should, but it doesn't test that branch of the logic.

EDIT: there are three problems, two of them fatal, one insiduous.

First, the if statements should read `if ($num != (count($keywords) - 1))`, instead of `if ($num != (count($keywords - 1)))`

Second, the $db object is not inside the function's scope, so i need to add `global $db` at the top of the function

Third, there's an extra underscore near the end; `$sql = $sql_1 . $_sql_2;` should be `$sql = $sql_1 . $sql_2;`

Thanks a million guys. i'd never have found these without your help.

Comment: i had checked it before, but there hadn't been anything useful, aside from warnings about setting a timezone (which i took care of). I was using tail to check it, though, and now i discover i've missed a whole slew of fatal errors, all related to an 'unsupported operand' on line 48 of the file which defines my custom function.  The odd thing is, line 48 is just an if statement. `if ($num != (count($keywords - 1))) {` and the error only started showing up three hours ago

Comment: I've found what i think was the original problem. Those if statements should read: `if ($num != (count($keywords) - 1))` Additionally, the `$db` object is not available iside the function, for some reason. I had to access it by way of the $GLOBALS array. This means that every place i had `$db->quote($somevar)` i needed to have `$GLOBALS['db']->quote($somevar)` after making these two changes, and getting rid of the errant underscore George Cummins pointed out, all is well.

Comment: You don't need to change everything to `$GLOBALS['db']`, just write `global $db;` at the top of the function to import it into the current scope. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: oh! even better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line references a non-existent variable:

```
$sql = $sql_1 . $_sql_2;
```

Should be:

```
$sql = $sql_1 . $sql_2;
```

Therefore, the query is invalid. You should check the output after executing the SQL query (`mysql_error()`, for example).

Comment: oh hey! how long has _that_ been there? Thanks for the catch. However, i went in and fixed it, and tested it again. It still is silently stopping execution at line 32, as before. I'm going to try putting my debug canary into the function being called. I'll see if i can get anything useful

Comment: well, that closing parentheses was taken care of in the else portion of the if statement. but that extra underscore was definitely a problem

Comment: @FitzmorrisPR: I overlooked that. Fixed.